# Android Generate Spinner List without XML or R.array

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner, listitem, arrays

I need the values within a spinner popup to be dynamically generated.

Specifically I am showing a list of years for a user to choose from. The year is the current year + 12 years in the future.

If I used strings.xml to make a string-array, then I have manually typed in list-items in that array. A few years from now, it will still be showing older irrelevant years. I would have to push an update or something. Lame.

I know how to get the current year in Integer form using

```
int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

but I need to populate an array with this year + future years. This is easy to do, but none of the adapter types for Spinner want to take int-arrays, or string-arrays for that matter.

I need a spinner that display items that were dynamically generated. The strings.xml contains pre-typed list-items so I cannot use that.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding them in as String-ified versions of ints one at a time?

I haven't tried compiling this, but something like this should work:

```
int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  adapter.add(Integer.toString(thisYear + i));
}
```

And then if you need them back as int's on the way out, use `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Ah yes, I understand but I don't how to declare and initialize the adapter! The way I have been initializing them takes a segment from the strings.xml file which is in R.array.expYr. 'ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.expYr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);'

Comment: I got it. instead of createFromResource I had to do new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> and add the string reference into it, after I generated the string.                                               `String years[] = new String[12];
  int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      years[i] = Integer.toString(thisYear);
      thisYear = thisYear+1;
     }
     
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> expYearAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the SpinnerAdapter (or BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter) class and do whatever you need with them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what I would do in this question's context?